# Infinite scrolling using custom animations in Recycler View not working Android

Tags: android, animation, android-recyclerview

I have use [Wasabeef](https://github.com/wasabeef/recyclerview-animators/) for Item animation in Recycler view and it works fine. I also want to add infinite scrolling for recycler, for this I am doing like this

```
    public abstract class InfiniteScroller extends RecyclerView.OnScrollListener {

    private int previousTotal = 0; // The total number of items in the dataset after the last load
    private boolean loading = true; // True if we are still waiting for the last set of data to load.
    private int visibleThreshold = 5; // The minimum amount of items to have below your current scroll position before loading more.
    int firstVisibleItem, visibleItemCount, totalItemCount;

    private int current_page = 1;

    private LinearLayoutManager mLinearLayoutManager;

    public InfiniteScroller(LinearLayoutManager linearLayoutManager) {
        this.mLinearLayoutManager = linearLayoutManager;
    }

    public abstract void onLoadMore(int current_page);

    @Override
    public void onScrollStateChanged(RecyclerView recyclerView, int newState) {
        super.onScrollStateChanged(recyclerView, newState);

        // Do Nothing
    }

    @Override
    public void onScrolled(RecyclerView recyclerView, int dx, int dy) {
        super.onScrolled(recyclerView, dx, dy);

        visibleItemCount = recyclerView.getChildCount();
        totalItemCount = mLinearLayoutManager.getItemCount();
        firstVisibleItem = mLinearLayoutManager.findFirstVisibleItemPosition();

        if (loading) {
            if (totalItemCount > previousTotal) {
                loading = false;
                previousTotal = totalItemCount;
            }
        }
        if (!loading && (totalItemCount - visibleItemCount)
                <= (firstVisibleItem + visibleThreshold)) {
            // End has been reached

            // Do something
            current_page++;

            onLoadMore(current_page);

            loading = true;
        }
    }
}
```

And this also works fine. Real challenge is when I combine item animation with infinte scroll doesn't work even though OnScroll listener is called and also loadMore() is called and it is adding item in the data source but not displaying it in recycler view.
Heres is the code.

```
 @Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                         Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_main, container, false);

    mRecylerView = (RecyclerView)view.findViewById(R.id.my_recycler_view);
    mLayoutManager = new LinearLayoutManager(getActivity());
    mRecylerView.setLayoutManager(mLayoutManager);

    initialize();

    mAdapter = new MyAdapter(persons);

    AlphaInAnimationAdapter alphaAdapter = new AlphaInAnimationAdapter(mAdapter);
    ScaleInAnimationAdapter scaleAdapter = new ScaleInAnimationAdapter(alphaAdapter);
    scaleAdapter.setDuration(1000);
    scaleAdapter.setInterpolator(new OvershootInterpolator());
    mRecylerView.setAdapter(scaleAdapter);

    mRecylerView.setOnScrollListener(new InfiniteScroller(mLayoutManager) {
        @Override
        public void onLoadMore(int current_page) {

            Log.i("Infinite Scroller", "Current page = " + current_page);

            insertNewItem();

        }
    });


    return view;
}
```

If I comment out animation lines it will scroll infinitely but not otherwise.
Please see the code and let me know what is going wrong.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So i found the problem myself and fixed it :)

For those who are having the same problem i will share my experience.

I was calling mAdpter.notifyItemInserted(position) but it should be scaleAdapter.notifyItemInserted(position).

Comment: where have you called scaleAdapter.notifyItemInserted(position).?